# Cómo instalar una extensión en Chrome con Python en todos los perfiles del navegador? Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, extensión-google-chrome, chromedriver

necesito ayuda. Tengo entendido que por defecto usando el siguiente código (usando chromedriver y selenium) instala la extensión pero crea un perfil temporal para cada sesión.

````
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Extension\\Proyecto\\extension.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path='C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Extension\\Proyecto\\chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.com')```

**Lo que quiero es que pueda instalar esa extensión en los perfiles (si es posible en todos) que tenga el navegador. Y leyendo en el website de chromedriver me encontré eso, pero no sé cómo implementarlo al código anterior**

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile");
````

Answer (score 0):

El codigo de ejemplo no esta en python, si te fijas en tu codigo original creas una clase Options(), es a esa clase Options a la que tienes que llamar al metodo addArguments y pasarle los argumento.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile")
```